# Should I make a HAS_Scope relation to Api- and IdenityResources instead of making a node with just 1 value

Tags: neo4j, identityserver4

I just started a github project for Identityserver4 with a neo4j backing store. 
(https://github.com/AndreSteenbergen/IdentityServer4.Contrib.Neo4jBolt) I am asking myself if I should make the relation (HAS_Scope) to the Resources directly, or if I should keep the nodes as they are now. I am very tempted to use HAS_Scope to the resources.

What are your ideas? Make a direct link, or just keep it as is?

[image: Neo4j Graph]

Comment: Can you describe your existing data model and your use cases?

Comment: The use case is I need a backing store for identity server4. As the rest of my application is written with a neo4j store, I would like to use neo4j as a backing store for identity server 4 as well.

At this moment I think it is best to merge the "ClientScope" nodes with IdentityResources (Red) and the ApiScope (called Claxe in grey). Because simply said, if the IdentityResource, or ApiScope does not exist, IdentityServer4 will provide an invalid_scope error.

Comment: Oh the data model is from Identity Server 4. Modelled in a graph, Blue: claim, Red: IdentityResource, Yellow/Orange: ApiResource, Purple: GrantType, Green are Clients

Answer (score 0):

I just debugged some more: when making an extra client with unknown scope, an error is given using that particular client. I think it is better to make sure the data is consistent in the first place.

Here is the second attempt, storing identityserver configuration in Neo4j. I have updated the github project accordingly. It works as a charm right now.

For the careful reader, I know it is not wise to use 1 secret for more then one client. A graph database can point out these strange things at once ....

[image: Second attempt, storing identityserver configuration in Neo4j]